# expressjs passport using Facebook login and Local login

Tags: facebook-graph-api, express, passport.js, passport-facebook, passport-local

I using the Passport middleware for ExpressJS and I can't find a way to use both the passport-local strategy and the passport-facebook strategy together. I would like to set it up so that a user will create an account on my site and then, if they want to, they can log into facebook so you can see your friends who also are using the site. However I don't know what the logged in user is when the facebook api data is returned.

When someone creates an account, their data (username, email, ect..) is stored in the database. When they then log into facebook I would like to just update the database and the session to now include some of the info returned by the Facebook API (facebookID, AccessToken, etc..). How can this be achieved?

Here is the code that I can use to access the returned facebook data. The line with User.findOne only works if the database entry already has been synced with facebook before though. **Is there any way that I can pass the req.session data to identify what the currently logged in user is and update their profile??**

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback",
    //callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000"
    profileFields: ['id', 'displayName']
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    User.findOne({facebookID: profile.id}, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      user.facebookID = profile.id;
      user.facebookToken = accessToken;
      user.save();
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the currently logged in user, you need to add the `passReqToCallback : true` option to the facebookStrategy

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback",
    //callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000"
    profileFields: ['id', 'displayName'],

    passReqToCallback : true // NEED THIS!!

  },
  function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    if (req.user) {
      User.findOne({username: req.user.username}, function(err, user) {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        user.facebookID = profile.id;
        user.facebookToken = accessToken;
        user.save();
        return done(null, user);
      });
    }
    else{
      console.log("attempted facebook auth from non-logged in user");
      return done(null, null);    
    }
  }
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with passport's facebook module, but I think you can access your local user database inside this:

```
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    User.findOne({facebookID: profile.id}, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      user.facebookID = profile.id;
      user.facebookToken = accessToken;
      user.save();
      return done(null, user);
    });
```

Something like this should be okay:

```
  var User = require('./models/user');
  passport.use(User.createStrategy());
  passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
  passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());


  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    //Make sure you have your user's email field and match that with 
    //the email field you got from Facebook

    User.findOne({email: profile.email}, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      user.facebookID = profile.id;
      user.facebookToken = accessToken;
      user.save();
      return done(null, user);
    });
```

I am not sure if `profile` has an email field but I think that should be somewhere in the profile.

However, I do understand that this will not work if your user only has username and password.

Comment: Thank you for your response! The local user does have an email but there's no way to be sure that the user entered email will be the same as their facebook email.

Comment: maybe you can try pass the `profile` into `done` and and use `done` method to render a page with facebookID, email, etc. Then you can use session data and do database insertion.

Comment: When I try this the session data is also replaced with the profile json. So I don't have a record of what the session data was before